# Programmatically adding a user control in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I'm trying to add a custom user control to  a Panel in a visual web part in Sharepoint 2010, with the following lines of code:

`MyUserControl userControl = new MyUserControl();`

MainContentPanel.Controls.Add(userControl);

However, my user control fails to load/render. The above code is triggered by clicking a link button.

Am I missing something, or is it just not possible to do it this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the usercontrols are stored in the 12/14 hive you need a clear reference to the path of the user control. Thats why you always need to do:

```
private const string _ascxPath = @"~/_CONTROLTEMPLATES/ProjectFolder/controlname.ascx"; 

MyControl MyUserControl = (MyControl)LoadControl(_ascxPath);

Controls.Add(MyUserControl);
```

However, you can also add it directly to the webpart/page/control by doing something like (determined by where you're placing it):

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="MyPrefix" Namespace="MyNameSpace.MyControl"
    Assembly="MyAssemby"%>

 <MyPrefix:MyControl ID="MyId" runat="server" />
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need to use the [LoadControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.templatecontrol.loadcontrol.aspx) method.  Also see [How to: Create Instances of ASP.NET User Controls Programmatically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c0az2h86%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: I actually tried that approach yesterday, but I used the LoadControl overload that accepts the type of the user control as the first argument:

`MyUserControl myUserControl = (MyUserControl)LoadControl(typeof(MyUserControl), new object[]{});`

That approach did not work for me, however, specifiying the physical location of the user control worked like a charm. Any idea why the first approach didn't work for me?